# Create a radio button in the scripts unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to add a radio button in scripts, so can the scripts variable be done in the sense of activating and closing it?

Comment: So you've tagged two different C# language versions, one released in 2007, and the other in 2010. You've also tagged a completely different language (the long-deprecated Javascript derivative, UnityScript) as well. Is there any reason why you've tagged these things? Can you clarify how each is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/radio-buttons.50723/) on the Unity Forums. If you scroll down to the last response you will find code that you can copy and paste to get the radio buttons. Although I do advise reading the entire thread so you have a better idea of how it all works, and will therefore understand how to make the changes you need for your project.